# I can't add or remove any programs

Tags: uninstall

I got this message when i try to add or remove any program

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/worker.py", line 285, in _process_transaction
    self.fix_incomplete_install(trans)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/worker.py", line 1021, in fix_incomplete_install
    with self._frozen_status():
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/contextlib.py", line 48, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/worker.py", line 1160, in _frozen_status
    shutil.copy(self._status_orig, frozen_dir)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/shutil.py", line 135, in copy
    copyfile(src, dst)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/shutil.py", line 99, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
IOError: [Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/aptdaemon-frozen-statusrqg05n/status'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
IOError: [Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/aptdaemon-frozen-statusrqg05n/status'
```

The next action to do is to clean up the partition containing the `/tmp` directory.

1. If `/tmp` is a separate mount point, you may simply reboot your computer.
2. If `/tmp` is part of your *root* partition read carefully this:
   [What do I do when my root filesystem is full?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/266825/what-do-i-do-when-my-root-filesystem-is-full/266835)