# Network Failure after Update

Tags: 14.04, networking, updates

Follow up to: [this question:](https://askubuntu.com/q/578420/372830)

After uninstalling a load of packages in order to free space on /boot for upgrades etc. I loaded Ubuntu software manager and was prompted to install an update, which I did, and then restarted. After restarting, the network connection is down. All settings are before, I hadn't touched `/etc/network/interfaces` before, only created/edited the network settings in Network Manager.

Also, the screen resolution is wrong and can't be changed. It would appear that I've lost network card drivers & graphics drivers. I have fixed this many times before in Windows but I wouldn't have a clue how to go about it in Linux?

**Outputs**

lspci | grep -i -e vga -e ethernet:
`00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 82G33/G31 Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02) 
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82541PI Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 05) 
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 02)`

nmcli dev:
`DEVICE  TYPE             STATE 
 eth1    802-3-ethernet   unmanaged`

Comment: Please post the output of `lspci | grep -i -e vga -e ethernet`, and the output of `nmcli dev`.

Comment: @muru  
lspci | grep -i -e vga -e ethernet:      
`00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 82G33/G31 Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82541PI Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 05)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 02)`  

nmcli dev:  
`DEVICE     TYPE              STATE        
eth1       802-3-ethernet    unmanaged    
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually fixed this by using a PCI network card. I was still getting the message in Network Manager that the device wasn't managed, so I followed the instructions in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71159/network-manager-says-device-not-managed). I am finally back to normal! Thanks for everyone's help.

P.S. Also fixed the display resolution being stuck at 640×480 by following [this article](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2014/10/31/solutions-for-low-screen-resolution-in-ubuntu-14-0414-10-and-virtualbox/) (#1 solution worked for me)