# How do I clean up my "home" drive or "/" to get some free space?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, disk-usage

I need to free some space on my drive:

```
Not enough free disk space:
The upgrade has aborted. The upgrade needs a total of 2,807 M free space on disk '/'. Please free at least an additional 1,396 M of disk space on '/'. Empty your trash and remove temporary packages of former installations using 'sudo apt-get clean'.
```

It's different from [How do I free up disk space?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5980/how-do-i-free-up-disk-space), as the solutions for that question weren't sufficient

Comment: Have you tried either of the solutions mentioned?

Comment: You'll have to explain how they are not sufficient. Edit your post to include the output of `lsblk` and `df -h`.

Comment: I have written the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The program `baobab` presents a graphic tree diagram of what uses how much space.  I find it useful for identifying where I wasted space, in particularly in my home directory.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful "/"  is your root aka main directory that contains entire system files & (Read more at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard))
Removing anything there may harm your system.
"home" contains user files & configuration, you can clean it up by removing unnecessary files & programs that you don't need. And by removing packages by

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

and

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

You can use [Bleachbit](http://bleachbit.sourceforge.net/) that will help by cleaning up your system !

Comment: And it could delete really critical stuff.

Comment: No, do **not** use bleachbit. Linux is good at keeping itself clean so if you are low on disk space, it's your fault not your system's. Bleachbit deletes important things, which is bad and redundant.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo -i
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
apt-get install --reinstall deborphan aptitude
deborphan
aptitude --purge remove `deborphan`
deborphan –-libdevel
aptitude --purge remove `deborphan --libdevel`
dpkg --purge `COLUMNS=300 dpkg -l | egrep "^rc" | cut -d' ' -f3`
OLDCONF=$(dpkg -l|grep "^rc"|awk '{print $2}')
aptitude purge $OLDCONF
```

A portion of the answer written in [How do I get free space? The trash can is empty](https://askubuntu.com/questions/600913/how-do-i-get-free-space-the-trash-can-is-empty)