# Deleting 'core dump' folders/files in root partition for space

Tags: 15.10, root, drive, df

On trying to upgrade my system, I keep getting a message that I need to free up space in the root partition. Here's the situation:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda5        20G   16G  3.1G  84% /
```

To me, that seems like a lot of space taken up, by I don't know what.. In [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/266825/what-do-i-do-when-my-root-filesystem-is-full), the one answer advises the OP to(among other things) do a search for core dumps filling up the disk with

`find / -xdev -name core -ls -o  -path "/lib*" -prune`.

I performed the search and came up with the following results.. Is it safe to delete these folders to get some extra space? Perhaps it's not possible to tell from just this output...

```
538670    4 drwxr-xr-x   3 root     root         4096 Mar 29 17:14 /usr/share/maven-repo/org/eclipse/jdt/core
 19809    4 drwxr-xr-x   2 root     root         4096 Jan 18 16:07 /usr/share/mlt/core
1201400    4 drwxr-xr-x  11 root     root         4096 Jul 25  2014 /usr/share/kivy-examples/tutorials/pong/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/dist/myapp/python-install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/core
1204401    4 drwxr-xr-x  11 root     root         4096 Jul 25  2014 /usr/share/kivy-examples/tutorials/pong/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/dist/myapp/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/core
181735    4 drwxr-sr-x   2 root     staff        4096 Jul 20  2015 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/astroid/tests/testdata/python3/data/unicode_package/core
181828    4 drwxr-sr-x   2 root     staff        4096 Jul 20  2015 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/astroid/tests/testdata/python2/data/unicode_package/core
992785    4 drwxr-sr-x  10 root     staff        4096 Oct 23  2014 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core
195891    4 drwxr-sr-x  11 root     staff        4096 Feb 28 15:48 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core
343499    4 drwxr-sr-x   2 root     staff        4096 Sep 23  2015 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core
179564    4 drwxr-sr-x   5 root     staff        4096 Jun 17  2015 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core
220980    4 drwxr-sr-x   5 root     staff        4096 Jan 18 13:02 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core
147573    4 drwxr-xr-x  12 root     root         4096 Jun 12  2015 /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/core
 73494    4 drwxr-xr-x   6 root     root         4096 Jan 18 16:33 /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core
  8054    4 drwxr-xr-x   4 root     root         4096 Jan 18 16:33 /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/IPython/core
173879    4 drwxr-xr-x   4 root     root         4096 Jan 18 16:30 /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode/wx/lib/pubsub/core
147017    4 drwxr-xr-x   4 root     root         4096 Jan 18 16:24 /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-3.0-gtk2/wx/lib/pubsub/core
556686    4 drwxr-xr-x  11 root     root         4096 Jun 12  2015 /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core
179822    4 drwxr-xr-x   5 root     root         4096 Jan 18 16:29 /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core
935953    4 drwxr-xr-x   3 root     root         4096 Jan 18 16:28 /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core
832349    4 drwxr-xr-x   3 root     root         4096 Apr 28 15:41 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/lib/visualvm/visualvm/core
832360    4 drwxr-xr-x   3 root     root         4096 Apr 28 15:41 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/lib/visualvm/platform/core
 98278    4 drwxr-xr-x   3 root     root         4096 Mar 30 05:01 /usr/lib/vmware-installer/2.1.0/vmis/core
198496    4 drwxr-xr-x   2 root     root         4096 Apr  5 14:16 /usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-35-generic/include/config/mlx5/core
197817    4 drwxr-xr-x   2 root     root         4096 Apr  5 14:16 /usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-35-generic/include/config/serial/core
204636    4 drwxr-xr-x   3 root     root         4096 Apr  5 14:16 /usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-35-generic/include/config/core
196798    4 drwxr-xr-x   2 root     root         4096 Apr  5 14:16 /usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-35/drivers/memstick/core
197048    4 drwxr-xr-x   2 root     root         4096 Apr  5 14:16 /usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-35/drivers/usb/core
196392    4 drwxr-xr-x   2 root     root         4096 Apr  5 14:16 /usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-35/drivers/net/ethernet/mellanox/mlx5/core
196980    4 drwxr-xr-x   2 root     root         4096 Apr  5 14:16 /usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-35/drivers/video/fbdev/core
196604    4 drwxr-xr-x   2 root     root         4096 Apr  5 14:16 /usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-35/drivers/gpu/drm/nouveau/nvkm/core
196550    4 drwxr-xr-x   2 root     root         4096 Apr  5 14:16 /usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-35/drivers/mmc/core
196203    4 drwxr-xr-x   2 root     root         4096 Apr  5 14:16 /usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-35/drivers/infiniband/core
107599    4 drwxr-xr-x   2 root     root         4096 Apr  5 14:16 /usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-35/net/core
107625    4 drwxr-xr-x   2 root     root         4096 Apr  5 14:16 /usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-35/sound/aoa/core
107795    4 drwxr-xr-x   4 root     root         4096 Apr  5 14:16 /usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-35/sound/core
784287 29524 -rw-------   1 root     root     38842368 Jan 31  2015 /etc/X11/core
```

Comment: What does this have to do with your title: "Changing forgotten root password" ?

Comment: @IanLantzy oops, that was an accident, sorry

Comment: Do not delete anything that you do not know what it is and where it comes from! I personally find `du` really helpful in these situations. `sudo du -hx / | sort -h` will show in increasing order (last = biggest) directories and files that eat up your space in the file system mounted as `/` (no other mounts).

Comment: @dadexix86 Thanks, indeed, I wouldn't do that, hence the motivation to ask this question. I am unfamiliar with 'core dump', but I believe, from what I have read, they are safe to delete, however, I can't tell whether all the results from the above search are even all core dumps.

Comment: To the extent of my knowledge, none of them is a core dump. Please note that 20GBs are not much, especially if you need a lot of libraries to program (like panda, wxwidgets and such that you have), because uncompress plain text files can be pretty big :)

Answer (score 0):

I honestly wouldn't go deleting anything from any of the directories listed in the output you posted, but perhaps I'm just overly cautious.

Rather than going around deleting things on your own, which is potentially hazardous, I would strongly suggest trying something like [bleachbit](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/bleachbit/), which can be installed directly from `apt-get`. You can additionally get it from [their website](https://www.bleachbit.org/download/linux).

I've used it previously on systems that somehow had ended up with lots of junk, and it does work. However, I've found Linux systems don't usually end up with a lot of extra files that need cleaned up, unless a user explicitly downloaded/stored something somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

how about increasing your system partition instead of deleting some unknown files that may cause system meltdown? If you got free space like unallocated space on the hard disk, try merge it to system partition in Disk Management. If you got free space in other partitions, shrink one of them and add the redundant space to system partition.