# Locate and remove unused files

Tags: delete, find

My hardrive is full! How do I locate and remove trash files? I can't even upgrade my ubuntu. I am a newbie with Ubuntu.

Comment: How do you know your trash is taking up lots of space?

Answer (score 0):

You can empty the trash by clicking the waste-bin on the bottom of the launcher, and clicking "Empty Trash."

In the Dash, search for Disk Usage Analyzer, and scan your hard drive. This will show you what files are taking up the most space, and where they are. Once you have some free space, I recommend using a program like BleachBit to clean up your junk files from time to time.

If the Disk Usage Analyzer shows that the root or / folder is full, please have a look at this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/266835/465804