# How to add more space to fileroot folder Ubuntu

Tags: filesystem

OK so my Home folder has 166gb of free space but my fileroot folder has max capacity of 8gb and its almost full how do I take from the Home folder and add space to the root folder?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have two partitions:  a home partition (w/ 166gb free) and a root partition (max 8gb).

This may be the answer you seek: [What do I do when my root filesystem is full?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/266825/what-do-i-do-when-my-root-filesystem-is-full)