# Low disk space in root

Tags: 18.04, filesystem

EDIT= added information requested by users

Space >

root > 20gb
swap > 8gb
/home > 300gb

I'm unable to figure out why I have no space whatsoever. I was able to find some commands to list, and this is my `df -h`

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs           3,2G  2,3M  3,2G   1% /run
/dev/sdb5        17G   16G  315M  99% /
tmpfs            16G   46M   16G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop1       15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/45
/dev/loop0       35M   35M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/818
/dev/loop2       91M   91M     0 100% /snap/core/6350
/dev/loop3      2,3M  2,3M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/260
/dev/loop4      3,8M  3,8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/57
/dev/loop5      141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/74
/dev/loop6       13M   13M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/139
/dev/loop7       54M   54M     0 100% /snap/core18/941
/dev/loop9      155M  155M     0 100% /snap/chromium/711
/dev/loop8       66M   66M     0 100% /snap/discord/93
/dev/loop10      68M   68M     0 100% /snap/sublime-text/58
/dev/loop11     143M  143M     0 100% /snap/slack/13
/dev/sdb7       281G  1,5G  265G   1% /home
/dev/sdb2        96M   31M   66M  32% /boot/efi
tmpfs           3,2G   56K  3,2G   1% /run/user/1000
```

I've created a 8GB for Swap, 20GB for root and 300GB for /home, so I have honestly no idea what is wrong. I followed some guide to dual boot with Windows 10 and I created from scratch on unused space.

I know this question has been already asked, but my limited knowledge on Ubuntu is too great.

I'm afraid randomly deleting files would only cause me to screw up my Windows installation (been there already).

I'm not even sure how to check the files on `/dev/sdb5`

```
[sudo] password for uriel: 
8,0K    ./media
4,0K    ./srv
12G ./var
128K    ./dev
16K ./opt
4,0K    ./mnt
128K    ./tmp
11M ./sbin
du: cannot access './run/user/1000/gvfs': Permission denied
2,3M    ./run
1,4G    ./home
813M    ./lib
13M ./etc
32K ./root
3,1G    ./usr
139M    ./boot
du: cannot read directory './proc/2093/task/2093/net': Invalid argument
du: cannot read directory './proc/2093/net': Invalid argument
du: cannot access './proc/3828': No such file or directory
du: cannot access './proc/6070/task/6070/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access './proc/6070/task/6070/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access './proc/6070/fd/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access './proc/6070/fdinfo/3': No such file or directory
0   ./proc
0   ./sys
2,9G    ./snap
4,0K    ./cdrom
13M ./bin
16K ./lost+found
4,0K    ./lib64
21G .
```

[gparted command as requested](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHFUc.png)

Comment: 20 GB (or 17 GiB as seen in the _df_ output) is not enough for a desktop system. For example, my 19.04 desktop Ubuntu installation (which I have been using for more than two months) is like this: / 18 GB used , /home 127 GB used (I have many virtual machines in my home folder). So I suggest at least 50 GB for the root partition, assuming your _swapfile_ resides on your root partition. Note that _df_'s options -h and -H behave differently and the -h option should be preferred (as you have done), because it displays in powers of 1024 and not 1000 (as the -H option).

Comment: You need to resize partitions, add screenshot of `gparted /dev/sdb` to question so someone could write answer how to resize, or search for resizing partitions question on this site. Is swap on /dev/sdb6?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do I do when my root filesystem is full?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/266825/what-do-i-do-when-my-root-filesystem-is-full)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `du` command to walk the file system and see what is taking space.  The process I use for this is to start at '/' (`cd /`) and run `du -h --max-depth=1`.  This will list the space taken by all files and directories in human readable format for the directory you are currently in.  You can then navigate into the largest directories and re-run the command to see the size of their contents.  Depending on what you find taking the space you can then decide what you need to do next.  If its junk than you can just delete the offending files and continue on; if the space consumption is legitimate (you need the files) than you'll have to look at larger partitions as already mentioned in the issue comments.