# Full 20gb root partition after 20 days of usage

Tags: partitioning

I installed ubuntu 19.04 20 days ago. My root partition has a size of [20gb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meaBG.png) and it is almost full. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UxJB.png) is what Disk usage analyzer outputs. According to dua the folder [/usr/lib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLzyN.png) is taking up the most space. I tried cleaning up with apt (clean,autoclean,autoremove),with [bleachbit](https://www.bleachbit.org/), [removing old snap versions](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/04/how-to-remove-old-snap-versions-to-free.html), [general suggestions](https://askubuntu.com/a/266835/853897) but have still little space left.

Should I resize my root partition?

Edit: After running dua as root I got [a better view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlT9r.png) of what takes up space. /root/.cache takes up 4.8GB and /var/lib/snapd/cache take up 1.2GB. What are those folders?

Comment: Neither `clean` nor `autoclean` remove anything stored in /usr, so their lack of progress seems like expected behavior. Similarly, snaps aren't stored in /usr.

Comment: The state in the pictures is after trying out the things I mentioned and thus they actually helped.

Comment: Run Disk Usage Analyzer and see what's taking up your space in /usr. DUA is included with Ubuntu. Do a desktop search for it (Windows key)

Comment: I already did that. One of the images attached are actually from dua.

Comment: DUA will tell you what is taking up all your space. So what is taking up all your space?

Comment: As already mentioned /usr/lib is taking up the most space.

Comment: Okay. So what in /usr/lib is taking up so much space?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99123/discussion-between-iason-manolas-and-user535733).

Comment: There are plenty of questions on here about deleting the contents of cache and .cache folders. If you delete it shouldn't give you any serious issues. I suggest you search for "delete .cache" on here and make your own mind up. If you browse the folders it should give you an idea about what might be affected.

Comment: Yes I guess my problem was that due to permission restrictions I did not get a full view of my system..

Answer (score 0):

I was only getting a partial view from the disk usage analyser and what helped me get a full view was to execute it as root using:

```
sudo baobab
```

In my case I deleted /root/.cache (after login as superuser) and the snapd cache under /var/lib/snapd/cache which in total accounted for 7GB

Comment: `sudo -H baobab` Never ever start graphically programs only with sudo. it can break ownership from important  files in your $HOME.

Comment: I didn't know that.. But does baobab even change ownership, I thought it's meant for inspecting purposes.