# Failing to boot up Ubuntu 18.04 inside VM

Tags: 18.04, virtualbox, docker

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 inside virtual Box(Host machine: Ubuntu 20.04), whenever I try to boot up the VM, I get the following message
[image: Message on Ubuntu Screen]

I tried running `sudo fsck -V /dev/sda1` on my host machine.

```
fsck from util-linux 2.34
[/usr/sbin/fsck.ext2 (1) -- /dev/sda1] fsck.ext2 /dev/sda1 
e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
fsck.ext2: No such file or directory while trying to open /dev/sda1
Possibly non-existent device?
```

`Command: sudo fsck -f /`

```
fsck from util-linux 2.34
e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root is mounted.
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.
```

Could someone please help me resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason behind this error was because of low storage and docker running in the background inside my VM. I was able to resolve it by following the below steps.

1. Boot your VM in recovery mode (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode), follow till step 7.
2. Type df and check how much space is consumed by your file system [image: (In my case /dev/sda1)]
3. Since my file system was full, I tried to get rid of few unnecessary files. You can check the space consumption of the files, by running the command `sudo du -hsx /* | sort -rh | head -n 40`

Ref: [What do I do when my root filesystem is full?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/266825/what-do-i-do-when-my-root-filesystem-is-full)

4. Finally `reboot` and it should work.
5. In my case, it did not work after step 4, so I followed steps 1-3 again and then did `snap remove docker` and then `reboot` and Voila! it worked.

OR

If you want to use docker inside your VM and you are facing space issues, then follow the steps mentioned in the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kyz9x71gEPI to extend the space on your VM, it shall solve your issue.