# 150GB root partition is full

Tags: server, 22.04, ssd, root

i run ubuntu server 22.04 LTS on a SSD 150GB. This SSD is suddenly filled up to 100%. I deleted some logs and files I was sure not to need anylonger.
But this gives me only 8% more space.

I read a lot of the similar posts, but it can not be to increase the partition.
I searched the big files. The server lists about ten items then does nothing . I only can cancel the search after 10 Minutes.

I checked the kernel.img and coredumps an deleted that mostly. This resulted in a 8% gain.

Do I realy have to reinstall the server?

```
    lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
loop0     7:0    0   9.6M  1 loop  /snap/canonical-livepatch/216
loop1     7:1    0   9.6M  1 loop  /snap/canonical-livepatch/229
loop2     7:2    0 101.5M  1 loop  /snap/conjure-up/1062
loop3     7:3    0 116.8M  1 loop  /snap/core/14784
loop4     7:4    0 116.8M  1 loop  /snap/core/14946
loop5     7:5    0  55.6M  1 loop  /snap/core18/2745
loop6     7:6    0  55.6M  1 loop  /snap/core18/2751
loop7     7:7    0  63.3M  1 loop  /snap/core20/1879
loop8     7:8    0  63.5M  1 loop  /snap/core20/1891
loop9     7:9    0  73.1M  1 loop  /snap/core22/634
loop10    7:10   0 128.9M  1 loop  /snap/docker/2883
loop11    7:11   0 128.9M  1 loop  /snap/docker/2893
loop12    7:12   0    37M  1 loop  /snap/gh/502
loop13    7:13   0  46.9M  1 loop  /snap/git-repo/18
loop14    7:14   0  91.8M  1 loop  /snap/lxd/23991
loop15    7:15   0  91.8M  1 loop  /snap/lxd/24061
loop16    7:16   0 262.5M  1 loop  /snap/nextcloud/34372
loop17    7:17   0   263M  1 loop  /snap/nextcloud/34542
loop18    7:18   0  53.2M  1 loop  /snap/snapd/18933
loop19    7:19   0  53.2M  1 loop  /snap/snapd/19122
sda       8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk  /MUSIC
sdb       8:16   0 149.1G  0 disk  
├─sdb1    8:17   0     1M  0 part  
└─sdb2    8:18   0   149G  0 part  /DATA/nextcloud/data
                                   /
sdc       8:32   0 931.5G  0 disk  /DVR
sdd       8:48   0 465.8G  0 disk  
└─md127   9:127  0 465.6G  0 raid1 /DATA
sde       8:64   0 465.8G  0 disk  
└─md127   9:127  0 465.6G  0 raid1 /DATA


    df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           795M  3.1M  792M   1% /run
/dev/sdb2       146G  139G     0 100% /
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/sda        466G   57G  409G  13% /MUSIC
/dev/sdc        916G  125G  746G  15% /DVR
/dev/md127      458G  2.5M  434G   1% /DATA
tmpfs           795M   32K  795M   1% /run/user/1000
```

Thanks in advance for responding.
Manfred

Comment: see this answers https://askubuntu.com/questions/266825/what-do-i-do-when-my-root-filesystem-is-full

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do I do when my root filesystem is full?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/266825/what-do-i-do-when-my-root-filesystem-is-full)

Comment: Had a bit of unusual case. Setting up full install to external SSD. I used rsync to copy a lot of data in data folders. And link data into /home. Somehow I managed to copy data into the mount point (before link?), so system did not show data but said partition was full. Only by viewing mount points and seeing data that should not be there from my other install could I tell I copied data to wrong place.

Comment: Thank you for your comments and links. These I have already studied and tried out. I will try to find out if I can view the mount points and consider if something is in the wrong place - so far I have no indication for that.

Comment: Please update your question with the output of the following commands: `lsblk` and `df -h`

Comment: And also `sudo du -hx / | sort -rh | head` which will show the biggest folders in your root filesystem.

Comment: It looks like your Nextcloud data is mounted to `sdb2`. I’m guessing your intention is to have it on your raid device. I’m not that familiar with Nextcloud, but I would think it needs reconfiguration and the data moved.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This seems to be the case, after you provided me with lsblk. I was offline. But now I will try to fix the nextcloud configuration.